# Firestore: Academic Timetable Structure

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out an efficient structure to store academic timetables in Firestore.

The problems I need to solve:

- Each course has its own start and end time
- Each course has its own duration in weeks
- There are a number of different timetables per course
- Need to be able to analyse attendance per class

Here's the structure I have now:

```
courses
 - course_id: string
 - duration: number (weeks, eg: 24)
 - end_time: number (timestamp of the last course day)
 - start_time: number (timestamp of the first course day)
 - name: string

modules
 - module_id: string
 - lectures: array
   - lecture_id
 - name: string
 - code: string
 - no_students: number

classes
 - class_id: string;
 - start_time: string (eg: 10:00)
 - end_time: string (eg: 11:00)
 - weekday: string (eg: Monday)
 - module: map (a copy of module object to reduce reads)
 - start_week: number
 - end_week: number

timetables
 - timetable_id: string
 - classes: array
   - class_id
 - duration: number (duration in weeks, eg: 11)
 - semester: number
 - week: string (current week, eg: 4)

users
 ...
 - timetable_id: string
```

A separate classes collection would allow for easier queering for comparison with attendance collection.

To read the timetable, I get the user doc, then get the timetable doc and then get the classes using `firestore.getAll()`. This results in a lot of document reads.

To update the current week, I would need to update each timetable doc.

What would be a better way of approaching this?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Why are you asking a better way? What is wrong with this one?

Comment: Just wondering if there's a way with less reads, since it'd be cheaper

Comment: You trying to optimize something that's not even a problem yet?

Comment: It is easier to optimise something now, than when it is in production

Comment: You haven't told us what is the issue with this one so it needs a "right now optimization".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "right now optimization". Is it a section in the question that would describe how I would like to optimise it?

Comment: You said "It is easier to optimise something now". So what's the issue with this schema so it require an optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to repeat important data across different document in Firestore.

Let’s say Diana want to read her timetable on phone, her timetable has 4 courses, 3 modules, 10 class. Put all these detail in one document, so when she want to view her timetable on app screen, the app read one document to fulfil her timetable. Every student will have heir own timetable document